Startup script to emulate keyboard shortcut keystrokes - dismiss app started in the background notification
I am running Ubuntu 24.04 noble on a Raspberry Pi 5 (arm64), with Wayland as window manager.
For background to my issue, I use the Snap package of ZapZap for Whatsapp, which auto starts on system startup. This creates the Ubuntu system notification "ZapZap started in the background", which affects the Dock icon notification count of unread messages. The ZapZap dock icon treats this notification the same as an unread message, so even with all messages read the ZapZap dock icon notification counter will still display a "1" relating to the "app started in the background system notification." This issue was was raised to the ZapZap developer community (https://github.com/rafatosta/zapzap/issues/238) but was subsequently closed and resolved in my particular case.
This particular notification can be dismissed with the following keyboard shortcut keystrokes:

Super+V (opens notifications)
Del (clears "app started in the background notification")
Esc (escapes notifications and return to the Desktop)

So far I am not aware of any extension or script approach that can override this one particular notification category, and emulate the behavior of Super+V→Del→Esc. I was not successful in installing and running notify-osd, if that might be a potential answer. I want to keep all other notifications on, so turning all notifications off for the app is not a solution.
So, my question: Can an executable startup script be written that will emulate the specific keyboard shortcut keystrokes, and can it be timed to execute immediately after the notification is displayed in order to clear it and return the ZapZap notification counter to it's correct count?
Thank you!

You could use xdotool to emulate the keypresses, e.g. xdotool key super+v 'Delete' 'Escape'. Put that in a bash script but not sure how you would time it as I don't know how the ZapZap app is being started. Quick and dirty method you could experiment with adding a script to the startup apps and maybe adding a delay sleep <seconds> to ensure it runs after. But if you can find out how/where the app is starting you could perhaps add the script into that process or replace with a script which starts the app then does xdotool. EDIT: I see you said Wayland, maybe an alternative Wayland tool?

thanks @codlord attempting with other tools similar to xdotool but for wayland....
